# How can I level and secure retaining wall steps?

Tags: repair, stairs, retaining-wall

We have some retaining wall steps that are in dire need of repair. We would like to re-level some of them and re-adhere all of the cap stones so they no longer rock.

Is it possible to create a spacer between the cap stone and the retaining wall block to level the stairs instead of having to dig out the entire step? If so, what would be the best way to create the spacer?

It looks like a previous owner has already done this with some sort of mortar on some stairs. I was thinking after using mortar or a plastic shim as a spacer, then using some polymeric sand to level the step. But then how would I adhere the capstone?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. Great first post. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how we operate.

Comment: The ideal would be to raise the front of the riser blocks. Shims would be plainly visible from below. Have you investigated whether they'll lift with a little force?

Comment: I have not, but I expected raising the risers to be a pretty heavy lift.  I could try to get a pry bar underneath it and then lift.  I'm guessing then something like road base would then need to be jammed underneath the block?  The way that the stairs were I believe improperly installed, is that the none of the risers sit on the riser block below it.  So the nose of a riser could easily sink creating the forward pitch.  This may complicate lifting them.

Comment: I don’t think they were improperly installed just time has taken a toll on them. The cap stones are thick enough that some mortar under the front should fix the slant , I would try and maintain a slight slant so the water runs down the stairs not to the back as that would accelerate any wash out of fill material.

Comment: Looks like failure of the embankment material to me.  *Something* has clearly caused the risers to tip over.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to quick fix masonry in the pictured condition is most likely not the way to go. Remove the treads and rebuild the the footing under the riser with pea stone, backfill with sand or pea stone and replace the treads. Slanting them downward is not a good idea if you live in a place where water freezes in the winter. If you want to add adhesive between the riser and tread use liquid nails for masonry. I’ve done tons of block stairways, to last they need to be relaid.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about forming a new set of concrete steps over the existing? You could lay new stone in the concrete treads to retain some of the original look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start at the footings. If its not level at the base it's already off level and plumb. Stairs need a slope for runoff. Using mortar will work to set a stair caps but will not let water through the interlock and will freeze expand and you'll be where you are now in no time.

Don't use pea gravel. Use sand or HPB. If winters are significant HPB is the way to go. Really it's always the way to go. It lets water pass through while providing a strong base lay. Do it right so you don't have to do it wrong 5 times. I'm not saying pea wouldn't work but after a 3/4 crush, HPB is the highest performance base you can use.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour]. Since we're a community of novices and experts alike, please expand your abbreviations. I have a lifetime of construction experience but I don't know what HPB is.